# What is a dualists response to Sean Carroll’s QFT objection to souls?

Tags: mind-body, quantum-physics, dualism, souls

https://www.preposterousuniverse.com/blog/2011/05/23/physics-and-the-immortality-of-the-soul/

He argues that given the universe operates on QFT, we would need to create new physics to account for souls interacting with the physical world. We would need an equation instead of the Dirac equation to explain how the immaterial soul interacts with our brains. Any dualist thoughts on this or did he basically just disproven dualism?

More particularly this arguments seems to target substance dualism.

Comment: The problem with his "cheesy Moon" analogy is that in the case of consciousness ("soul") there is quite a lot that "laws of physics underlying everyday life" arguably do not describe or explain, what dualists call [the hard problem of consciousness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_problem_of_consciousness). One can say that they are not meant to do that, and perhaps this is true, but then his premise "the laws of physics underlying everyday life are completely understood" is either false or moot. Of course, dualists still *do* have to explain the interaction between laws and consciousness.

Comment: Are you asking about [interactive dualism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/dualism/#Int), or are you including philosophical theories which assume consciousness is [epiphenomenal](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/dualism/#Epi) in your question? Carroll's argument would seem to only concern the former, not the latter.

Comment: I'd say he makes an argument against dualism.

Comment: @Dcleve would seem to have a thought in this subject

Answer (score 2):

Current physics is obviously incomplete or incorrect. It does not predict the existence of consciousness. But we know consciousness exists. Plus we have the known problems of unifying QM and general relativity.

So of course we need new physics because the current physics does not explain the whole world. Consciousness is a part of the world.

Comment: are you talking about the behavior associated with consciousness such as speech (the 'easy problem'), or subjective experience considered independent of behavior (the 'hard problem')? If the latter there is no obvious reason why physics would ever address this, it is only about predicting measurable changes in the physical world.

Comment: Well, I'm talking about both. I think the "easy" problems will not be explained without the existence of consciousness... ie: I think consciousness isn't just epiphenomenal. Physics can disprove this by showing that current physics in the brain predicts our social behavior. It has not done anything like this. If consciousness is epiphenomenal, then you're right that physics can't say anything about it.

Comment: I think you use "consciousness" ambiguously. Physics does not predict what dualists mean by "consciousness", but we do not know *that* exists. Problems of unifying QM and relativity are arguably moot, as the effects involved likely do not register at the relevant scale. So I do not think either is the problem with Carroll's argument, it is unsound for other reasons.

Comment: Physics does not predict the existence of "subjective experience". But Hypnosifi is right that there is no reason to expect physics to explain this since it may not have measurable changes. But if physics sticks to that role, then it has nothing to say on the matter if consciousness or souls are epiphenomenal.

Comment: BTW, I would add that Sean Carroll doesn't have the view that physics merely "makes predictions"... to him physics the more general role of explaining the world. So by his own view on what physics should accomplish, I'd say physics is incomplete.

Comment: With regards to QM and relativity not being on the relevant scale, doesn't Penrose's objective orchestrated reduction work with both gravity and QM?

Comment: *I would add that Sean Carroll doesn't have the view that physics merely "makes predictions"... to him physics the more general role of explaining the world* Showing how something is predicted by an underlying theory is a type of explanation, but do you think he believes physics gives explanations which don't fit that mold? Having read his book *The Big Picture* I'm pretty sure he doesn't, but if you think he does, can you quote a statement of his, or link to one?

Comment: @Hypnosifl, so if a dualist was to say the soul is a mere recipient of phenomena, and causes no changes in the physical world... would Sean Carroll say that physics has nothing to say on the matter?

Comment: Physics does predict, or at least can explain, "subjective experience", as *physicalists* understand the explanation (Dennett is an example). And Penrose's [Orch OR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orchestrated_objective_reduction#Background) is what Carroll calls "crazy", and not only him. For his argument the question is not whether physics is incomplete (it is), but whether this incompleteness is plausibly relevant. So your first paragraph kind of misses the point.

Comment: I don't think Sean Carroll would say physics can rule out epiphenomenal philosophies like the type of dualism Chalmers sometimes advocates. And Orch OR doesn't "explain" subjective experience, it just postulates that certain quantum phenomena are associated with consciousness. But even if Orch OR were correct about these effects being necessary to intelligent *behavior* Chalmers would say it'd still be logically possible to have a zombie whose brain operated on Orch OR principles, so it doesn't really solve the hard problem philosophically.

Comment: @Conifold, how does physics explain subjective experience? I mean... are you saying we can look at a physical system and predict whether or not subjective experience is going on based on physics alone?

Comment: @Hypnosifl, what I take as an "explanation" for subjective experience is... a set of basic laws from which we are able to predict which states of matter have associated with them "subjective experience" and what the content of the subjective experience is. I think something of this sort is at least partially within the realm of science... Dealing with "pain" is a part of science at least. I think any more of an "explanation" is impossible. Why does the universe obey this set of laws instead of another is not going to be explained.

Comment: Dennett wrote Consciousness Explained, Carruthers wrote [Phenomenal Consciousness](http://www.mit.edu/~abyrne/CarruthersReview.pdf) dedicated specifically to explaining the "subjective feel" (to him this means showing how neurology produces privately only accessible content), and they'll probably answer your question affirmatively. My point is not that they are right, but that there is nothing "obvious" about what we "know", it is itself a point of contention between physicalists and dualists. Carroll's argument is flawed because it begs the question, not because he overlooks the obvious.

Comment: @Conifold "because it begs the question" ...I'm confused; how is Carroll's argument begging the question?

Comment: @HWalters "The laws of physics underlying everyday life are completely understood" according to physicalists, not according to dualists (taking "physics" broadly, as Carroll must for his argument to go through). It assumes a premise opponents reject, hence begs the question against them.

Comment: @Conifold "Beg the question against x", meaning "assuming a premise your opponents reject", is new to me; "beg the question" to me means "presuming your conclusion".  But even so: "according to physicalists" ...seems like you're reading the phrase differently than I am.  By my reading, Carroll is saying that it's an obstacle for dualists that there are no "known holes" in physics (my <600c rephrasing; see the link under that phrase, search for "that is in apparent conflict"; read paragraph).  So said dualist may indeed have a premise; charitably, they might even be right...

Comment: ...but even if they are right, there's no "known holes" in the everyday physics, and that is an obstacle for them.

Comment: @HWalters I agree that dualists would have to explain how "consciousness" relates to the laws of physics in defending *their* thesis. But in Carroll's argument the burden is not on them. It can be epiphenomenal, or subtly influence collapses, etc. *He* has to rule out such exploits, not assume physicalist understanding of consciousness/soul from the get-go. And considering that physicalist explanations of "consciousness" so far arguably fall short assuming it as a premise makes his argument essentially circular. And otherwise, no holes in physics is moot, as this is something it does not cover

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106578/discussion-between-h-walters-and-conifold).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a dualist, so bear that in mind, but I can see a couple of immediate logical objections to Carroll's argument.

First — and perhaps this is an unfair critique, even if accurate — Carroll is using a straw-man representation of religious beliefs. The idea of a 'personal' (identity preserving) soul that exists entirely separate from the physical plane is an unsophisticated conceptualization. Yes, it's a common conceptualization among both theists and atheists (which is why this critique may be unfair). But there are other ways of thinking about the biology/consciousness distinction than to treat consciousness as (a) an epiphenomenal byproduct or (b) a disconnected externality, but Carroll doesn't even hint at such. Why not think of consciousness as an emergent property of biology? Why not consider that the consciousness/biology relationship is a two-way street, not a one-way lane starting in biology? Either consideration would make his argument much harder, and as a result much more convincing if he succeeds.

That brings me to the second critique. Although I'll give him bonus point for invoking the Dirac equation, by using it Carroll is implying that the soul (or whatever) has to operate directly on electrons. This is that one-way lane approach: Carrol presumes that any 'spiritual' influence has to start deep down in the basic physics and biology of the brain and work its way up to influence consciousness. But it's well-known that the conscious mind can influence biology: people can slow their breathing or their pulse by act of will; a mere thought or perception can kick off the biological processes of anger, happiness, grief, etc. All we have to do is conceptualize that the 'spiritual' connects at the mental level and works its way down to influence the body, and the Dirac equation no longer applies.

Carroll's argument hinges on the preconception that consciousness is epiphenomenal and fully reducible to biology. That is not something that has been established by science, and without that preconception his argument doesn't have a lot of traction. I mean, I'm sure people will quibble with what I've said — I've just laid out a couple of critiques without building them into a full argument of their own — but I can't personally see a way *around* these critiques.

Comment: On the first objection, I think (charitably) he can do that because his main target is afterlife. Assuming something more sophisticated, like property dualism, it is not so easy to explain how the "soul" goes on while its physical carrier disintegrates. Hylomorphists had great difficulty explaining how "substantial forms" can persist without their matter since Aristotle and Aquinas, and modern property dualists, like Chalmers, would probably discard afterlife. Substance dualism is far more compatible with it.

Comment: @Conifold: Well, I don't know. It seems to me that that the 'afterlife' objection only works because because he ties any concept of a 'soul' to a particular physical body (by presuming that it has to rise to consciousness through fundamental physical principles).  If we presume the opposite, that it connects with consciousness and works down to the physical, then it could perfectly well exist across incarnations, merely by connecting to new consciousness. In that case it's not that it 'floats free', but that it starts 'free' and connects intermittently.